# Is it possible to unexpose port by Docker Compose if it is exposed in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Assume I have such Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["some", "app"]
```

And such docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    exposes:
      - 6000
```

After I do docker-compose up -d docker ps outputs:

```
CONTAINER ID        NAMES      STATUS              CREATED             PORTS
3315ec1be1b3        app        Up 41 hours         41 hours ago        5000/tcp, 6000/tcp
```

Is it possible to unexpose port 5000 and leave only 6000?

Comment: Possibly related https://superuser.com/questions/803772/remove-exposed-port-from-docker

Comment: @Ayushya yeah this is probably true one. Could you pls publish answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way is to create a new image: usually, you always want your docker container and images to be reproducible. If you manually change something deviating from your image, you rob yourself of that behaviour (something someone else managing the infrastructure you're working in would expect.)

Right now, directly managing the DNAT with iptables is the way to go. An implementation of this approach is given in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/808124/396312).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think this is a good way. Actually I was looking for something like UNEXPOSE, or RESET_EXPOSES.

Comment: I do not think that it is going to be implemented. As any implementation to change the default behavior of containers created by dockerfile would violate the reproducible behavior of container.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, any dockerfile and container will inherit all the ports that were once configured. It is part of the metadata of an image. There is no UNEXPOSE but there is a workaround to "`docker save`" an image with all layers, edit the metadata, and "`docker load`" back the modified image including history.

As I had that task regularly, I have created a little script to do the work, please have a look at [docker-copyedit](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit).